# Dependency injection does not work when added with interface

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection, singleton

when I add a service to the configure services method in my startup class

```
services.AddSingleton<IGoogleApi, GoogleApi>();
```

I get the following error.

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[0]
>         An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'MultilanguageTranslatorAPI.Services.GoogleApi' while attempting to activate 'MultilanguageTranslatorAPI.Controllers.WordsController'.

If I change that into (removed interface)

```
services.AddSingleton<GoogleApi, GoogleApi>();
```

the error is gone, everything works fine. But why? What is wrong with my class? Constructor might be suspicious.

```
public WordsController(TranslatorDbContext context, UserManager<User> userManager, GoogleApi api)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _context = context;
        _api = api;
    }

public class GoogleApi : IGoogleApi
{
    private readonly TranslationClient _client;
    private readonly string jsonPath = "Json\\MultilanguageTranslator-82ea38c537d3.json";

    public GoogleApi()
    {
        using (var jsonStream = new FileStream(jsonPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            _client = TranslationClient
                .Create(GoogleCredential.FromStream(jsonStream));
        }
    }
```

**How should look the correct code for this implementation?**
Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 4):

Your controller is taking the concrete type, `GoogleApi` in it's constructor, here.

```
public WordsController(TranslatorDbContext context, UserManager<User> userManager, GoogleApi api)
```

It should instead take the type `IGoogleApi`, like so:

```
public WordsController(TranslatorDbContext context, UserManager<User> userManager, IGoogleApi api)
```

When you use the concrete type, the IOC container isn't able to use it's singleton mapping of `IGoogleApi` to `GoogleApi`, as that's not the type of dependency requested.

Comment: Thanks, now works fine! I got confused by that other hings weren't interfaces (maybe they should be?)